# SSRS RunningValue contained within another RunningValue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a SSRS report that shows the waste minimised/disposed by a city for a given time period. The report looks like this:

[image]

I am using the `RunningValue()` function to determine the 'Cumalative Quarterly' totals e.g. the cumulative quarterly total for 'Waste Generated':

```
=RunningValue((Fields!WasteGenerated.Value), SUM, "WasteYear")
```

The 'Waste Diverted' is calculated with the following formula:

```
=((Fields!WasteMinimised.Value / Fields!WasteGenerated.Value))
```

And the 'Quarterly Waste Diverted' is still straight forward as:

```
=(Sum(Fields!WasteMinimised.Value) / Sum(Fields!WasteGenerated.Value))
```

Next I want to calculate the "Cumulative Quarterly Waste Diverted" based on the `RunningValue()` of 'Waste Minimised' and 'Waste Generated':

[image]

[image]

I tried this by having nested `RunningValue()` functions:

```
=RunningValue(((RunningValue((Fields!WasteMinimised.Value), SUM, "WasteYear")) / (RunningValue((Fields!WasteGenerated.Value), SUM, "WasteYear"))), SUM, "WasteYear")
```

However, with this I get the following error:

> The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox43.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses a RunningValue function in an outer aggregate. RunningValue functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

I cannot think of another solution other than `RunningValue()` to complete this 'cumulative' function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually pretty simple if you think about it. I don't need to have any nested `RunningValue()` functions. I just need to apply the 'Waste Diverted' formula to the `RunningValue()` totals:

```
=RunningValue((Fields!WasteMinimised.Value), SUM, "WasteYear") / RunningValue((Fields!WasteGenerated.Value), SUM, "WasteYear")
```